# Node.js WebSockets Send Message

Tags: node.js, websocket, messaging

I'm trying to come to terms with how WebSockets work in Node.js but I'm having some trouble with sending a message.

I have my WebSocket server configured as follows (index.js)

```
var ws = require("ws");
var wsserver = new ws.Server ({
   server: httpserver,
   port: 3030
});

wsserver.on (
   "connection", function connection(connection) {
      console.log("connection");
   }
);
wsserver.on (
   "open", function open(open) {
      console.log("open");
   }
);
wsserver.on (
   "message", function message(message) {
      console.log("message");
   }
);
```

This seems to be working ok because I can establish the connection using

```
var wscon = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.20.88:3030");
```

Which then gives me the connection output on the server. If I try to use send though nothing seems to happen and no error messages

```
wscon.onopen = function(open) {
  wscon.send("test message");
}
```

I must be missing something but I don't know what

Answer (score 2):

I might have an answer for this but I'm not entirely sure just yet, I'm going to put this here just in case.

I think the problem is that the message listener is added to the wrong object (the server object), I tried to add the message listener to the connection object passed to the server and it seems to be working but I'm not 100% sure why

```
wsserver.on (
   "connection", function connection(connection) {
      console.log("connection");
      connection.on (
         "message", function message(message) {
            console.log("message : " + message);
         }
      );
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Which dependency works for me?**

I have been using socketIO for a while now and it works perfectly for Node.JS API's / servers. There are millions of tutorials online for this framework and I'll tell you one them.

**How to install?**

If you use NPM as your package manager in Node.JS just down it with the following command:

```
npm install --save socket.io
```

In case you're using yarn you can install socketIO as following:

```
yarn add socket.io
```

> **Setup the socket server:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

// Used for serving the HTML page (if used)
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// Listen for new connections
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

*Now in index.html I add the following snippet before the :*

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

> In your front-end you are able to fire of an event via the socket by calling the following function / code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

> In our case we emitted an event called chat message. So in order to receive the value send over the socket connection we call the following code in our backend / api:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

and that is basically how you use socket with the library SocketIO. Hope this helped fixing your issue!

Comment: I love socket.io <3, that is the WebSocket framework I normally use but I wasn't able to get it working with Node Static and WebRTC. Once I figure this out though I'm def going to revisit this for socket.io. Thanks a bunch for the great answer though

Comment: @Trent No worries mate. I hope this gets you going. ;) Take care bud!

Comment: @KevinVugts - curious to know your experience of using socket.io at production?

Comment: @kta It works quite well in production for me. I only use it for minor parts in the app but it does it's job. What about you?